# jQuery droppable render position. Seems to be moved to the left

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a group of jqueryUI sortable items and a droppable box with a "x" inside.
The droppable box is in a side-bar positioned on the right of the screen.
The problem is that the droppable hover effect and event executes when i drag the sortable item outside the box, a little pixels to the left. It seems to be a problem of positioning of the droppable object. The graphic is in a place and the feel is in another place.

Here is the example code:
http://jsfiddle.net/G3rCN/3/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sortable paragraphs has a 100% width, if you set them to be ie 200px wide then they will not interfere with the droppable X

http://jsfiddle.net/G3rCN/7/